# Grouping Content by Date in Views

Tags: views, nodes, datetime

I'm trying to group content by date in views but instead of utilizing 'Fields' to stylize it, I'm trying to style using 'Content'

Here is an example of what I see right now:

```
Note Post Title

  This is a test comment 1
  John Doe
  Posted Date October 7, 2013 - 11:15 AM

  This is a test comment 2
  John Appleseed
  Posted Date October 7, 2013 - 11:20 AM
```

Here is what I'm trying to achieve:

```
October 7, 2013

   Note Post Title 1
     This is a test comment 1
     John Doe
     11:15 AM

     This is a test comment 2
     John Appleseed
     11:20 AM
```

Answer (score 0):

For grouping the content by date field, you may try the following:

- Add one extra date field in the fields section. (This field will be used for grouping)
- In `Format` -> `settings`, select that date  field for grouping

[image]

Comment: Ankit, thanks for the reply but I'm attempting to do grouping with using Format -> Show -> Content http://oi40.tinypic.com/5yemv6.jpg

Comment: @ApurvParikh One another way to do from UI is using the `aggregation`, enable the aggregation and than in the fields settings select group together

Comment: I'm not using fields, need a way to do grouping with format -> content

Comment: Why don't you want to use fields?